# Updating config xml file and save it using powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, config

I need to update this config file in such a way that, all the values of 'newVersion' needs to be updated to a single value.

```
<configuration>
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding>
  <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="A" 
publicKeyToken="5d861ad8ad8cd06f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-65534.65534.65534.65534" newVersion="4.0.0.103" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="B" publicKeyToken="ae714df8cd90bc8f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-65534.65534.65534.65534" newVersion="4.0.0.103" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="C" publicKeyToken="22955931b98512b6" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-65534.65534.65534.65534" newVersion="4.0.0.103" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="D"
                                  publicKeyToken="585a888b4a9ba2e3"
                                  culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-65534.65534.65534.65534"
                                 newVersion="2.5.0.1286"/>

              </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

I have tried this below

```
$appconfig='file location'
$doc = (Get-Content $appconfig) -as [Xml]
$obj = $doc.configuration.runtime.assemblyBinding.dependentAssembly
$obj2 = $obj.assemblyIdentity | where {$_.name -eq 'D'}
$obj.bindingRedirect.newVersion="1.1.1.1"
echo $obj.bindingRedirect.newVersion
$doc.Save($appconfig)
```

I know this would change only to the "D" part, how can change to the above A,B and C also. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(gc C:\temp\config.xml) -replace '(newversion=)".*?"' ,'$1"1.1.1.1"' # if you want to save the file add |sc c:\temp\config.xml
```

Comment: `'newversion=.*'` will also match and replace the closing "/>" and thereby render your XML-file invalid. I'd rather use: `(gc C:\temp\config.xml) -replace '(newversion=)".*?"', '$1"1.1.1.1"'`.

Comment: Keep in mind, that this replaces the value of ALL occurences of "newversion", regardless of which node it is an attribute. The answer of @dotnetom is more save.

Comment: @ManuelBatsching thanks for the remarks. Btw the op said he wants to replace all occurrence and did not mention any restriction. Using replace is more intuitive in this case I think.

Comment: Thank you Manuel and Kayasax, yes it is true that even closing "/>" got replaced and I just added 'newversion="%buildnumber%/>"' immediately. However, how should I understand -replace '(newversion=)".*?"', '$1"1.1.1.1"'.. If the question mark is representing only a single character, then I think /> are 2 characters right... correct me.. I might be completely wrong on this... thanks to both of you again..

Comment: I've edited my answer based on your remarks, `?` wasn't necessary.

Comment: This is my new requirement. How can I put new values to newVersion in the same document. A and B will have 0.0.0.1 and C and D will have 0.0.0.2 .. I am unable to post the entire script here because of chars limitation. But.. its exactly the same as it is in my question..I have not changed anything to that script..
But, powershell says Property 'newVersion' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable. This is really frustrating.

Comment: The star-quantor in the regular expression `.*"` is greedy, which means that it will match as much as possible. In your case it will match any character until it finds the last `"` in the line. This works in the example above only if `newversion="someValue"` is the last attribute in the line. If not, it will mess up your XML-document again, because it will also match any attributes that follow `newversion`. The `?` removes this danger by changing the behavior of the star-quantor to "non-greedy". So I'd like to encourage you to keep the `?`.

Comment: @Bhaskar would you mind to update your question to reflect your full requirement?